# using pulltorefresh library

Tags: android

I'm using the PullToRefresh library:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/

The problem I have is when the list is short and doesnt use the full screen:

[image]

The "Tap to refresh..." is always shown at the top, and I would like it would be hidden as it is when the list uses the full screen

I'm trying to modify the code, but I'm not able!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [pending pull request](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/pull/40) for this exact issue, perhaps you can try to integrate it into your library?